# draw histogram using Weka in java code

Tags: java, weka

I'm totally new to Weka. I'm trying to use Weka from my Java code. I need to build a histogram like you see in the right-bottom corner in the Weka Explorer at the screenshot.
I found these class but I don't know how to use it
import weka.gui.visualize
[image]